# How to change behaviour of stubs?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Can I change the behaviour of a stub during runtime? Something like:

```
    public interface IFoo { string GetBar(); }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRhino()
    {
        var fi = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();
        fi.Stub(x => x.GetBar()).Return("A");
        Assert.AreEqual("A", fi.GetBar());
        fi.Stub(x => x.GetBar()).Return("B");
        Assert.AreEqual("B", fi.GetBar());    // Currently fails here
    }
```

My code example still fails in the given line, `fi.GetBar()` still returns `"A"`.

Or is there another trick to model stubs whose behaviour changes over time? I'd rather not resort to using `fi.Stub(...).Do(...)`.

Ah, probably I just need hardcopy of the fine manual for somebody to hit me over the head with it. It looks like it should really be obvious, but I can't find it.

Comment: Try `fi.Stub(x => x.GetBar()).Return("A").Repeat.Once();` and `fi.Stub(x => x.GetBar()).Return("B").Repeat.Once();`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**WARNING**

*Changing the behaviour of stubs is a code smell!*

It typically indicates that your unit tests are too complicated, are hard to understand and are brittle, breaking easily on correct changes of the class under test.

Check out:

- [xUnit Test Patterns][1]
- [The Art Of Unit Testing][2]

So, please: **only use this solution if you can't avoid it**. In my eyes this article borders on bad advice - however there are rare situations where you really need it.

---

Ah, I figured it out myself. Rhino supports record/replay mode. While AAA syntax always keeps the objects in replay mode we can switch to record and back to replay just to clear the stub's behaviour.

It looks a little hackish, however ...

```
    public interface IFoo { string GetBar(); }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRhino()
    {
        var fi = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();
        fi.Stub(x => x.GetBar()).Return("A");
        Assert.AreEqual("A", fi.GetBar());

        // Switch to record to clear behaviour and then back to replay
        fi.BackToRecord(BackToRecordOptions.All);
        fi.Replay();

        fi.Stub(x => x.GetBar()).Return("B");
        Assert.AreEqual("B", fi.GetBar());
    }
```

*Update:*

I'll be using this in the future, so things look a little nicer:

```
internal static class MockExtension {
    public static void ClearBehavior<T>(this T fi)
    {
        // Switch back to record and then to replay - that 
        // clears all behaviour and we can program new behavior.
        // Record/Replay do not occur otherwise in our tests, that another method of
        // using Rhino Mocks.

        fi.BackToRecord(BackToRecordOptions.All);
        fi.Replay();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use terminology that is native to Rhino Mocks, make it ClearExpectations

Comment: @Richard: Behavior added with `.Stub` does not set expectations. You are thinking of Behavior added with `.Expect`.