# How can I replace an already declared stub call with a different stub call?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

If I have a Rhino Mock object that has already has a stub call declared on it like this:

```
mockEmploymentService.Stub(x => x.GetEmployment(999)).Return(employment);
```

Is there anyway I can remove this call to replace it with something different e.g.:

```
mockEmploymentService.Stub(x => x.GetEmployment(999)).Return(null);
```

The reason I ask is that I want to set up some generic mocks to be used in multiple unit tests and then allow each unit test to tailor the calls where necessary.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use this extension method to clear the behavior of stubs (or the behavior+expectations of mocks):

```
public static class RhinoExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the behavior already recorded in a Rhino Mocks stub.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ClearBehavior<T>(this T stub)
    {
        stub.BackToRecord(BackToRecordOptions.All);
        stub.Replay();
    }
}
```

I picked that up from [this other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770013/rhino-mocks-how-to-clear-previous-expectations-on-an-object/770083#770083), or maybe it was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630037/rhino-mocks-change-behaviour-of-stubs).

Comment: Thanks Wim, the only problem is that it would clear all stub calls so I would have to reset them all rather than just override the one I am interested in.

Answer (score 12):

I use the `Repeat.Once()` or `Repeat.Times(x)` methods where it will move on the next stub\expectation when the limit has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

I actually use the stub as a method that receives the expected return and it works.

```
private void StubDoSomething(bool expected) => Dbs.Stub(x => x.DoSomething(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<object[]>.Is.Anything)).Return(expected);
```